# Using a combination of two fields as key in a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, hash

I need to store a c# dict where I can store members based on a IntPtr and a enum (castable to int if that helps). In other words, if I get the same match of IntPtr and the enum (named sp_playlist_type) I need to be able to get the same result out, but only then (that's also important). I've figured I'd make a struct containing the two, and override GetHashCode(), but then I'd need a hashing-algorithm that doesn't create duplicates for the two numbers, and generates the same result every time the same two numbers are present.

Comment: Standard mistake.  A hash only needs to reproduce the same number, it doesn't have to be unique.  Equals() takes care of identity.

Comment: @Hans: Does `Equals` get called from the `Dictionary<T1,T2>`?

Comment: As has already been mentioned, the hash code does not have to be unique. However, two objects that are equal must have the same hash code as each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think based on the way Tuple's GetHashCode and Equality is alredy created, you could have:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<IntPtr, YourEnum>, YourResultType>
```

Provided you are on .NET 4.0 of course.

Answer (score 7):

> then I'd need a hashing-algorithm that doesn't create duplicates for the two numbers

This actually is not true.  You need to override `GetHashCode()`, but it can have collisions.  You want to minimize collisions in your hash codes, not eliminate them.

This is actually fairly easy to do.  A common option is to just use the XOR of the hash codes of both members of the struct, or something similar to that.

Comment: Reed, correct me if I'm wrong, but I beleive the Tuple<> class overrides GetHashCode to be a combination of the hash codes of the members (and similarly for eqality).  Couldn't we just have: Dictionary<Tuple<IntPtr, enum>, Whatever>?

Comment: @James: Tuple<T1,T2> would work fine if he didn't want to write a custom struct.  I often will write my own struct, especially if it's going to be used a lot, since it's more clear - but Tuple would work fine.

Comment: True, very true.  I go back and forth on whether I like Tuple or custom structs.

Comment: Simple XOR isn't a very wise choice with `enum`s that can take on very few values; only the lower-order bits will differ, potentially slowing down probing hash tables.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it is use an string as key,  you combine in this string both values. For example:

```
private string GetKey(IntPrt prt, sp_playlist_type playlist_type)
{
    return string.format("{0}#{1}", prt, type)
}
```

To use it, you use something like:

```
mydic.add(GetKey(ptr, playlist_type), myvalue);
```

Comment: Playlist suggests it's not a big list, but it's not exactly a high-performance solution is it?

Comment: This is going to get slow pretty quickly due to the string conversion. It's also not the best hash ever.

Comment: It's a common pattern to create a hashcode and ensure the correct distribution. On this way you don't need to create a new struct or class and override GetHashCode method to can use it as key. And it's valid in all framework versions.

Comment: You can use XOR inside instead of the string.format. The idea it's to use the method instead of create a new class or struct and override the GetHashCode. If you are using 4.0 use Tuple is the best option

Answer (score 0):

It's not strictly necessary to override GetHashCode, since as others mention there is no requirement for it to be unique.

However it may be desirable to override Equals for your struct for performance reasons, [as described in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dts52z7.aspx).

In which case it is [recommended to override GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182358(v=vs.80).aspx).  Probably in this case an XOR of the IntPtr and the enum (the LS 32-bits of the IntPtr on a 64-bit system).

Comment: IF you override Equals, then you MUST override GetHashCode.

Comment: If by MUST you mean it's strongly recommended, then I agree - that's the point I'm trying to make.  But the Framework doesn't oblige you to, and if you create an Equals implementation that is equivalent to the default for a struct, you can get away without doing so.

Comment: I mean MUST as in if you don't do it, you cannot be assured of proper access to it in a dictionary. (i.e. Your code will be deeply flawed.) To your point about creating an equivalent implementation, I would say in that case you aren't really overriding Equals then.